# Passing data to angular function on changing html slider input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to pass a value on changing the html slider input in AngularJs.

```
<input type="range" value="30" min="0" max="0" id="set-value" />
```

Angular function:

```
$scope.passValueHere = function(value) {
  //TODO Here
}
```

I don't want to use any plugins or whatever. Just a simple answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st thing you need to use `ng-model` directive with value, which will be available in controller `$scope` & then place `ng-change` event over that input element.

**Markup**

```
<input type="range" value="30" min="0" max="0" id="set-value" 
  ng-model="sliderModel" ng-change="passValueHere(sliderModel)"/>
```